# Windows Scheduler Capabilities when running c# compiled code

Tags: c#, windows, email, outlook, scheduler

Okay so I have a application that runs every hour through windows scheduler. It runs successfully, and I can tell that by windows scheduler. When I click on the executable the application runs with no issue.

When I run the same application through windows scheduler it does not work as expected.

It closes outlook as it should, but it doesn't reopen it.
Rather it starts the executable but the Outlook application doesn't show up on my desktop.

My application should do this: Close my email, send emails, open outlook.

I need to close Outlook in the first place because if I don't close it before I try to send emails it will try to access the data-file, and since I have my email up on my desktop before hand windows scheduler can't open the data-file.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {        
        foreach(Process proc in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if(proc.ProcessName.Equals("OUTLOOK"))
            {
                proc.Kill();
            }
        }

        //Removed code which sends emails.

        openOutlook();
    }

private static void openOutlook()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.exe");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution that I came up with was to close outlook before emails were being sent.

> If a process of Outlook is open then kill all instances; proceed with sending emails as needed. Open Outlook manually after the program has finished.

A possible alternative is to create some VBA that attaches emails at a certain time. You could also look into the other links that were provided on this page.

Answer (score 3):

Automating Outlook from a windows scheduler (service) is not a good idea.

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) article.

As a workaround you may consider using a low-level API - Extended MAPI. Or any third-party wrapper around that API such as Redemption.

Comment: So that could explain why I can run the application as a user and it works fine, but when I run it through the scheduler it doesn't work completely.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduler is a service that runs in a local user context different from the currently logged user. Outlook will be opened in that user context and the currently logged in user will not see it.

Comment: I tried adding outlook.exe to the scheduler after it runs my executable file. That seemed to not work either the task never ends. As in the task can't open the executable or something.

Comment: Again, scheduler is a service and Outlook (or any other Office app) cannot be used from a service.

Comment: That's not exactly true though because it sends emails just fine. I just can't open the outlook executable through the application.

Comment: Yes, Outlook in a service works fine until it breaks in a really spectacular fashion.

Comment: So it would be better to use smtp or something then huh?

Comment: Yes. Raw SMTP will work, but the drawback is that the sent message will not be saved in the Sent Items folder. Are you hitting an Exchange server or a POP3/SMTP one in that Outlook profile?